# Prove that a sequence converge.

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

I need to do this exercise:
Assume $0 \le a \le b$.Do the sequence $\{(a^{n} +b^{n})^{1/n}\}$ diverge or converge?. If the sequence converge find the limit. Well what I did is:

I computed the limit and I got:
 $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (a^{n} +b^{n})^{1/n}\ = b  $$
And I bound my sequence with:

$$b < (a^{n} +b^{n})^{1/n} \le (a+b) $$
Then I said :

Now, we have a sequence bounded from below, since $b$ is not in $\{ a_{n} \}$ and $\{ a_{n} \}$ is not empty we have that $b$ is an accumulation point, then for an arbitrary neighborhood of $b$ we have infinite members of $\{ a_{n} \}$, therefore the sequence converge to $b$.

Am I right?. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can conclude $b$ is an accumulation point.  At the moment it is just a lower bound.  See Dark Chocolate's answer.

Comment: Is because we have the result: 

Let S be a nonempty set of real numbers that ins bounded from above (below) and let x=supS(infS).Prove that either x belongs to S or x is an accumulation point of S.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $b < (a^n + b^n)^{1/n} < 2^{1/n}b$

Comment: thank you :),but,Then, do my sequence does not converge to b?

Comment: Since $\lim_{n\to +\infty}2^{1/n}=1$, your sequence **does** converge to $b$. The mistake in your argument is that we cannot state that for any sequence belonging to an interval $I$, the left endpoint of $I$ is an accumulation point. Think to $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ given by $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. $a_n\in[0,1]$, but $0$ is not an accumulation point.

Comment: Thank you @JackDAurizoThen how can I fix my argument? and do the result help or I cant use it?

Comment: Please, Can you help me ? I want to know if I am right, If not Can you help me to fix it please? Thank you

Comment: Then, do I can leave like this or I have to fix something?¿, thank you, I need your help :).