# How do I solve this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sin^n(1)+\cos^n(1))^n$

The options are:

(A) $\cot(1)$

(B) $\tan(1)$

(C) $\cos(1)$

(D) $\sin(1)$

Comment: What did you try? Show us your effort.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I tried binomial expansion, but that doesn't seem to help. I don't know how to start with this.

Comment: Are you sure you've transcribed the problem correctly?  Since $0<\sin{1},\cos{1}<1$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^n{1}=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^n{1}=0$.  The limit of the sum is $0$ and raising it to the $n$th power just makes it go to $0$ faster.

Comment: Perhaps it should be $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sin^n(1)+\cos^n(1))^{1/n}$? Then it is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923219/prove-that-a-sequence-converge

Comment: Without seeing the options i did exactly the same thing. But the options are as quoted above.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you copied the question correctly?

I will go for e) **none of the above**.

$|\cos(1)| \lt 1$,$|\sin(1)| \lt 1$

So the expression inside the exponent goes towards $0$, and certainly your limit goes towards $0$.

Comment: I have the question with me. I agree with your argument though.